# Access view model required error message data annotation attribute from code - MVC, Razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I created method ExtendedTextBoxFor and i want to access view model message for atribute that i'm sending in as a parameter. I can access IsRequired attribute without problems but error message seems to be non public property, is there any way to access it?

So far i have this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ExtendedTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        if (metadata.IsRequired)
        {
            //Read error message from ViewModel
        }

        return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, (string)null, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Error message is in metadata > PrototypeCache > Required > ErrorMessage as shown on picture below:

[image: Wanted value]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with this in case someone needs it. Thank you all for help

```
private static string GetErrorMessage(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        string retVal = String.Empty;

        var customTypeDescriptor = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(metadata.ContainerType).GetTypeDescriptor(metadata.ContainerType);
        if (customTypeDescriptor != null)
        {
            var descriptor = customTypeDescriptor.GetProperties().Find(metadata.PropertyName, true);
            var req = (new List<Attribute>(descriptor.Attributes.OfType<Attribute>())).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (req != null)
                retVal = req.ErrorMessage;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```